# Pick-a-Color dropdown display inside a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors

Perhaps this question is a duplicate, but I didn't find an answer for my problem.

I have a `div` with id`tees` inside a modal body

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_Setup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" data-backdrop="static" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-wide">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Col1</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                        <label class='col-md-2 control-label'></label>
                        <label class='col-md-5 control-label'>Col3</label>
                        <label class='col-md-2 control-label'>Col4</label>
                    </div>
                    <div id="tees" style="margin-bottom:20px; padding:0;">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" style="float:left;" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="changeColours()">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

I'm adding thing inside my div programmatically

```
$("#tees").empty();
for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < Tees.length; i++)
            $("#tees").append("<div id='" + (i + 1) + "' teeid='" + Tees[i].Id + "' class='col-md-12 form-group'><label class='col-md-2 control-label' style='font-size:120%'>Tee " + (i + 1) + "</label>" +
                "<div class='col-md-5'><input id='teename_" + (i + 1) + "' value = '" Tees[i].Name + "'/></div>" +
                "<div class='col-md-2'><input id='colb_" + (i + 1) + "' value='" + Tees[i].BackColor + "' class='pick-a-color form-control' inline-dropdown='true'></div>")
}
$("#tees").append("<div style='clear:both'></div></div>")
$(".pick-a-color").pickAColor({ showSpectrum: false, showSavedColors: true, saveColorsPerElement: false, fadeMenuToggle: true, showHexInput: false, showBasicColors: true, allowBlank: false });
```

I don't know if the `Pick-a-Color` dropdown can be displayed outside the modal, because right-now it increases my modal size and I need to scroll to get to my desired color. Can anyone please help me with it?

Comment: you could apply a position: fixed or absolute on the color drop down if you can target it with css. this will allow you to place it where ever on the screen you want. Also note you might need to add a z-index .

Comment: I've tried using position fixed and also top:0 but I want to display the dropdown near the button that was pressed to choose the color but to not stay inside the modal, instead the rest of the dropdown to be displayed outside the modal, without affecting it's size

Comment: position absolute should work. try giving position relative on the div container and position absolute on the drop down list, you should be able to push it around with left and top css property